# Connect to SFTP via a http proxy in lftp?

Tags: sftp, http-proxy, lftp

I am behind a http proxy (http://localhost:8080). I want to connect to my sftp server via this http proxy using the lftp command. How to do that ?

My lftp command now is

```
lftp sftp://...
```

How to connect through the Http proxy ?

Comment: Sure it's possible, using the CONNECT method that is also used for HTTPS over proxies. However, port restrictions usually apply.

Comment: @DanielB Can you pls. help how to integrate that with the lftp ?  Also can you share about the commands like ```nc ``` as ```CONNECT``` is not availbale to me . Port of the proxy has 22 allowed, so not worrying about that